# check type of nested object in python

Tags: python, types

I have a list of objects in python, and I want a better overviw of the type of the object. By using the builtin `type` class you can get the type of an object in python but that would only be the top level. In a better example.

```py
>>> type([1, 2, 3, 4])
<type 'list'>
```

However I would want something like.

```py
>>> type([1, 2, 3, 4])
<type 'list[int]'>
```

I am also aware that you could sample the first element of the list  and get the type of that, but that is not good for my purposes. I would preferably be able to compare a list or nested type with a typing-modual-like anotation e.g

```py
if type([1, 2, 3, 4]) == List[int]:
    ...
```

Comment: Well, a list in python can have different types of elements. What would you expect to be returned if you have for example an int and a string? Why not check whether it is a list and whether the first element is an int? You could even write your own function that checks that and use that in your if clause.

Comment: I would like tthe function to return a Union type from the built in typing modual, or a similar method. Simpily I would like any method that would indicate that there are two types that share the same itterable object. The data I would like to test is also extremely nested, e.g, [("a", ("b", "c")), ("a", ("b", "c")), ("a", ("b", "c")), ("a", ("b", "c"))]

Comment: So you would expect an output like `list[tuple[string, tuple[string]]]`? That becomes very complex very fast in the general case where this might be any combination of any types of python...

Comment: I would, I am aware that you could get a tree of types by using python's match case, but I would then need to get a tree of types, which brings us back to our original problem.

Comment: What you want doesn't exist at runtime. You can give a *name* a static type of `list[int]` (`x: list[int] = [1,2,3]`), but the value will always have type `list`.

Comment: Given a list, you can check if every element is an `int` (`all(isinstanceof(x, int) for x in some_list)`), but the list itself doesn't "know" the types of its elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to write your own function for that, at least as far as I know (if anybody has a better suggestion, please let us know).

This could for example be something like this:

```py
def get_type(your_list):
  set_of_types = set()
  for element in your_list:
    try:
      iterator = iter(element)
    except TypeError:
      set_of_types.add(type(element))
    else:
      set_of_types.add(frozenset(get_type(element)))
  return set_of_types
```

This only works for lists, if you have for example a `dict` within your list it becomes more complicated.

It is a recursive call, so any sub-lists/sets/tuples should be in there as well.

You can then use the returned set to check what types you have in your list. Does this help?